# Devise Admin authenticate_admin! not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to use 'authenticate_admin!' from devise. I am currently using https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role OPTION 2. I am getting the error that authenticate_admin is not defined. Is there a way for me to utilize devise's admin macros and other functionalities while still using option 2?

Answer (score 0):

authenticate_admin! method is created only if you have created a **devise Admin** model in your program. As you are going with Option 2, you have to use current_user.admin? to check to see if a user is admin as well.

I always recommend going with Option 1, as it leaves very little room for inadvertent mistakes of assigning admin privileges to normal user.